# Does Kendo UI Mobile support RTL?

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I want to build a mobile HTML5 app based on AngularJS, phonegap and a UI framework. I am considering using Kendo UI Mobile for that but my app is going to be in Hebrew, meaning it will be Right-To-Left. I know Kendo UI for web has support right out of the box for RTL, but does Kendo UI Mobile has it too?
Any other recommendations for UI frameworks for that purpose?

Comment: I don't think Kendo UI Mobile has support out of the box for RTL, because if there was such thing you should see RTL in Kendo UI Mobile Demos like Kendo UI for web demos.

Comment: Also please take a look at this: [`Right-to-left UI Guidelines`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858682/right-to-left-ui-guidelines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently Kendo UI Mobile doesn't support RTL out of the box.